# Storing Custom Model as Column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How would I go about storing ClassB as a column in ClassA? I've seen examples of both the `TypeDecorator` and using a relationship, but I'm not quite sure what the best way to go about this is. A clear example and explanation would be great. Thank you!

```
class ClassA(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # transactions = db.Column(ClassB) <-- Want to achieve this somehow

class ClassB(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    recipient = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
```

Comment: Don't store it as a column (a composite type of sorts), but a reference to it – a foreign key.

Comment: A clear example and explanation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship